# How can I write the next step exactly below the previous step in the equation without repeating the L.H.S. of the equation?

Tags: spacing, equations, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, subequations

If I want to write in latex as per following image, how can I write it?

[image: exact below writing]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
    P(\text{accident occurs and spill develops})&=P(A \cap B)\\
    &=P(A|B)P(B)\\
    &=\dfrac{3}{15000}\cdot \dfrac{8}{50000}\\
    &=0.000000032
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT**:

[image]

Comment: More generally, the amsmath package has several good environments for widely-used equation layouts, and its user guide has a good visual reference table of them.

Answer (score 12):

The following solution also employs an `align*` environment (cf [@RaffaeleSantoro's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/661854/5001)), but also takes care of several typographical niceties such as using upright lettering for a "math operator" (such as the "probability operator" `\P`), uses `\mid` instead of `|` to denote conditioning, and replaces `0.000000032` with exponential notation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{amsmath} % for '\DeclareMathOperator' macro and 'align*' environment
\let\P\relax                % undefine the existing '\P' macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\P}{P} % 'probability operator' (upright lettering)

\usepackage{siunitx} % for '\num' macro
\sisetup{exponent-product=\cdot}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\P(\textnormal{accident occurs and spill develops})
  &= \P(A \cap B) \\
  &= \P(A\mid B) \P(B) \\
  &= \frac{3}{15000} \cdot \frac{8}{50000}\\
  &= \num{3.2e-9}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just answered to all the question posed. Nothing less, noting more.

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro - I apologize for creating an impression that I was somehow criticizing your answer, which indeed perfectly replicates the OP's screenshot. For sure, my answer also uses an `align*` environment as the main formatting device. My intent was merely to show how one could add a few typographic niceties.

Comment: No Problem! I am not a pro and I try to give the simplest answer: the only one I can.